# sftp server without using linux user accounts

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I have seen a lot of articles on how to create secure shells for user accounts that just need sftp only access.  I am trying hard not to create Linux user accounts.  I have been trying a number of web based file managers, but they are clunky and unreliable or way out of my price range.

I am looking for sftp solution that would allow me to use my own db (mysql) for authentication and lock them down to their own virtual home dir.  This isn't a Linux /home dir, this is my virtual one.  I can't see a way to use openssh at this point.

So I am looking for some advise on which direction to go or products to try.

Thank you

Brad

Comment: Most sftp servers support [virtual users](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd#Virtual_users_with_TLS.2FSSL.2FFTPS_and_a_common_upload_directory_-_Complicated_VSFTPD). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @int_541 the document you linked is for vsftpd, which is used to create an FTP server. It has the option of supporting FTPS (FTP over TLS), as well as virtual users. SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is not related to FTPS in any way.